# How does this code create a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

There is a good post in [1] about move semantics. I'm fairly comfortable with them, but there are still some edge cases that I'm not sure about -- specifically, about returning rvalue references. For example, the link says that this creates a dangling reference:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Shape>&& flawed_attempt()   // DO NOT DO THIS!
{
    unique_ptr<Shape> very_bad_idea(new Square);
    return std::move(very_bad_idea);   // WRONG!
}
```

I don't quite understand the error. The function is declared to return an rvalue ref, and it's doing that with the std::move().

How is the dangling reference created?

[1] [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

Comment: Ask yourself: When does the `very_bad_idea` object get destroyed?

Comment: Do you understand why the equivalent code, but returning an lvalue reference and not going through std::move, would also create a dangling reference?

Comment: The `unique_ptr<Shape>&&` rvalue reference is a **reference**.